# Getting feed from server client model

Tags: c++

In a typical client server model,  what does it mean to subscribe or unsusbscribe to a feed?  Is there a generic codebase or boilerplate model or set of standard procedures or class design and functionalities involved?  This is all C++ based.  There's no other info other than the client is attempting to connect to the server to retrieve data based on some sort of signature.  I know it's somewhat vague, but I guess this is really a question of what are things to keep in mind and what a typical subscribe or unsubscribe method might entail.  Maybe something along the lines of extending a client server model like http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm.

Comment: A feed is something that produces content.  Subscribing to a feed means you want to be notified when new content is available on that feed.

Comment: Subscribing to a feed is often a client only subscription whereby the client records your interest in a specific data feed and regularly checks the feed server for updates.

On the other hand email subscriptions work by the client registering an account with the server and the server sending regular emails to the client's email account.

I think you need to nail down what you are trying to do a little more.

Comment: Thinking about it generically I suppose the model is that the client regularly connects to the feed server and it may, or may not need to authenticate with the server to retrieve the data. If it does need to authenticate then it will have to have previously set up an account with the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily an information architecture question. "Subscribing to feeds" implies that the server offers a lot of information, which may not be uniformly relevant to all clients. Feeds are a mechanism by which clients can select relevant information.

Concretely, you first need to identify the atoms of information that you have. What are the smallest chunks of data ? What properties to they have? Can new atoms replace older atoms, and if so, what identifies their relation? Are there other atom relations besides replacement?

Next, there's the mapping of those atoms to particular feeds. What are the possible combinations of atoms needed by a client? How can these combinations be bundled in two ore more feeds? It is possible to map each atom uniquely to a single feed? Or must atoms be shared between feeds? If so, is that rare enough that you can ignore it and just send duplicates?

If a client connects, how do you figure out which atoms need to be shared? Is it just live streaming (atoms are sent only when they're generated on the server), do you have a set of current atoms (sent when a client connects), or do you need some history as well? Is there client caching?

It's clear that you can't have a single off-the-shelf solution when the business side is so diverse.